# Reset local view of remote branch

Tags: git

Assume I have a Git repo that looks like this

```
* abcdefa (master) tip
* 1234567 (origin/master) base
```

If someone else fast-forwards `origin/master` from `1234567` to `abcdefa`, my local repo will not change until I `git fetch`. Once I `git fetch`, my local git will look like

```
* abcdefa (master, origin/master) tip
* 1234567 base
```

Is there a way to undo this `git fetch`? That is, can I make git believe again that `origin/master` is still at `1234567` rather than `abcdefa`, without actually changing the remote? Clearly this state is not completely inconsistent, since this is the state I was in before running `git fetch`, so I assume there is some way to return to it.

I realize this sounds like a huge case of an XY problem because what I want is very unreasonable, but (a) I think I need to do this for an company-internal CR tool that I unfortunately can't share many details about, and (b) outside of practical applications, I'm curious to know how to do this, or if it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forcibly move a remote-tracking name with `git update-ref` (which takes the full name).  If reflogs are enabled—which they normally are—you can undo the last `git fetch` that updated `origin/master` with:

```
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master origin/master@{1}
```

It's probably better to fix whatever tool you are using to accept commit hash IDs or things that parse to such hash IDs; then you can just run:

```
tool origin/master@{1}
```

or:

```
tool $(git rev-parse origin/master@{1})
```

directly.